# Помощь по jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#lichcab').click(function(){
                    $('#vhod-errorModal').что тут дальше написать не знаю
                })
            });
```

При клике на объект с `#lichcab` запускается модальное окно. Я хочу этим скриптом одновременно с тем модальным окном вызвать ещё одно с `#vhod-errorModal`. Написал, что смог. Дальше не могу догадаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте готовые решения для модальных окон. Модальное окно на то  и модальное, что монопольно показывается.

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: /*половина ширины*/;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

А в обработчике клика вы напишите

```
$('#vhod-errorModal').addClass("modal");
```

А на закрытие окна - убирайте класс.

```
$('#vhod-errorModal').removeClass("modal");
```